# C++ How to check the last modified time of a file

Tags: c++, file-io, last-modified

I'm caching some information from a file and I want to be able to check periodically if the file's content has been modified so that I can read the file again to get the new content if needed.

That's why I'm wondering if there is a way to get a file's last modified time in C++.

Comment: what's wrong with good old C `stat` call?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, it's a unix system call, so it's not cross-platform

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall that's why I did not answer.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is no language-specific way to do this, however the OS provides the required functionality. In a unix system, the `stat` function is what you need. There is an equivalent `_stat` function provided for windows under Visual Studio.

So here is code that would work for both:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#ifndef WIN32
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

#ifdef WIN32
#define stat _stat
#endif

auto filename = "/path/to/file";
struct stat result;
if(stat(filename.c_str(), &result)==0)
{
    auto mod_time = result.st_mtime;
    ...
}
```

Comment: So there's nothing that I can use that will work both on UNIX and on Windows? :/

Comment: Modified to add windows support

Comment: this worked great after blind coding waiting 10min to let travisci end remote compilation :)

Answer (score 26):

since the time of this post, c++17 has been released, and it includes a filesystem library based on the boost filesystem library:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem

which includes a way to get the last modification time:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/last_write_time

Comment: In order to use std::filesystem on macOS with Apple's developer tools, you must assume Catalina or later.

Comment: The returned time is unusable portably in C++17. But from C++20, we can cast between chrono clocks, and convert the returned time to a systime which is portable.

Answer (score 9):

You can use boost's `last_write_time` for that. Boost is cross platform.

[Here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/libs/filesystem/doc/operations.htm#last_write_time)'s the tutorial link for that.

Boost has the advantage that it works for all kinds of file names, so it takes care of non-ASCII file names.

Comment: since c++17 also as part of standard library
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/last_write_time

Answer (score 2):

Please note that there are [some limitations](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/libs/filesystem/doc/operations.htm#last_write_time):

> ... The [time] resolution is as low as one hour on some filesystems... During program execution, the system clock may be set to a new value by some other, possibly automatic, process ...

Answer (score 1):

Also note that after copying a file (on Windows) the copy's last_write_time is the last_write_time of the original file rather than the time the copy was created, as one would naively think.

Answer (score 0):

This cross-platform library (Mac, Windows, Linux) is simple to add to a project. It uses #ifdef's to compile the right implementation.

https://github.com/jameswynn/simplefilewatcher